# What should I make sure to get when doing the last part of the Main Quest Line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have just flown on Odahving to Skudalfn. I understand that once I finish the main quest, I will be unable to return to here or to Sovngarde.

What are some of the things (unique items, shouts) I should make sure I get, both before I get into Sovngarde, and before I leave Sovngarde?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Skuldafn Temple area has a word wall that teaches you part of the  [Storm Call](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Storm_Call) shout.

[Nahkriin](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nahkriin_(creature)) is a dragon priest with a [mask](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nahkriin_(item)) you'll want to grab. His staff is also unique, if generally uninteresting, and you'll probably pick it up just to gain entry to Sovngarde anyhow.

Everything else in Skuldafn is generic leveled stuff, and there's no notable loot in Sovngarde itself other than (as pointed out in the comments) some unique clutter like the ox head on the dining table.

Comment: Sovngarde has unique clutter, I think. Like an ox's head on the dining tables. You can't eat it.

Comment: That is correct, there's an ox head in the dining hall that is unique.

Comment: Can you pick that stuff up? I never noticed that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I read through the wiki pages for the last parts of the main quest, and the only unique item I found is that you should make sure to loot the mask from the Dragon Priest that is guarding the portal to Sovngarde. Other than that, there doesn't appear to be anything missable.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that by reloading a save before entering the ruins, you are able to get prepared with anything you have in the regular Skyrim world before you can kill Alduin. One you think you're prepared, ride Odahving to Skuldafn. However, there are also useful things in Skuldafn Temple. There is some loot inside the ruins. Nahkriin also has a dragon priest mask which is indeed useful. Don't forget about the staff too!